# Convert API response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am making an Ajax call and getting this response:

```
console.log(data);
{"valid":true,"when":"Today"}
```

When I try to read it,

```
var res = data.valid;
console.log(res);
```

it shows undefined. I am trying to add a condition:

```
if (res==true){
    /*code*/
}
```

Actual code:

```
    $.ajax({
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": url,
        "method": "POST",
        "processData": false,
        "contentType": false,
        "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
        "data": form,
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data); // {"valid":true,"when":"Today"}
            var res = data.valid;
            console.log(res); // Undefined
            if (res==true){
                 $("p").addClass("test");
                 $("#callForm").hide();
                 $("#buttonClick").hide();
                 $("#success").show();
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: You should show the actual code....

Comment: @epascarello: check now

Comment: Looks like your sever is not returning JSON content type heading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here variable `data` may be a string so parse it to `json` using `JSON.parse();` so that it will work.

```js
var data='{"valid":true,"when":"Today"}';
var myJSON = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(myJSON);
//Here Data is  a string so parse it to json using JSON.parse();
console.log(myJSON.valid);
```

Complete code looks as below.

```
$.ajax({
   "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": url,
  "method": "POST",
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form,
  success: function(Data){
 console.log(Data); //{"valid":true,"when":"Today"}
  var data=JSON.parse(Data);//convert into json
  var res = data.valid;
  console.log(res); //undefiend
   if(res==true){
       $("p").addClass("test");
       $("#callForm").hide();
       $("#buttonClick").hide();
       $("#success").show();
       }
       }
})
});
```

Try this. Now it will works.

Comment: A safer alternative would be to specify a dataType so that if the server one day decides to return a correct content type, the code won't stop working. Also... your comment is wrong. `//convert into json` it's already json, that's the problem.